# How can I execute /bin/ls with assembly in mac os?

Tags: macos, assembly, executable, mach-o

I need to know how can i execute bin files or executables like /bin/ls from assembly. I'm new to assembly and very low level programming. I only found the code for linux:

```
xor eax, eax
xor edx, edx
push eax
push long 0x736c2f2f    ; "sl/"
push long 0x6e69622f    ; "nib/"
mov ebx, esp
push eax
push byte 0x2f
mov esi, esp

push eax
push esi
push ebx
mov ecx, esp
mov eax, 0x0b
int 0x80
```

As far as I know that mac syscalls should be 0x2000... and the order of the registers for the arguments. I don't know how to change the code to make it work on mac.

P.S.: Why is the path written backwards?

Comment: try the command gdb

Comment: Just write it in C and "compile" it with `-S`.

Comment: What you have there is something called *shell code.*  It's a special programming technique for writing exploits and is not reflective of idiomatic programming style.  Do not program like this unless you know what you are doing.